# Star token in Scheme not working in Chrome match pattern

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension. I'm trying to add a button where the user can toggle if images should be blocked on a specific site no matter what the scheme is.

Here's some sample (JS) code that shows my problem quite simple:

```
chrome.contentSettings.images.get({ primaryUrl: "*://*/*"}, vars => {
        console.log(vars.setting);
});
```

So in theory this should output if images are blocked or allowed on "all" sites.
If I run this code I get the following error:
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: The URL "*://*/*" is invalid.`
When I change `"*://*/*"` to `"https://*/*"` it logs allowed (or blocked) just like it should. But obviously this is not what I want because it specifies the scheme (it should also track http).

So the main question is: has something changed in the pattern syntax?
Cause [this article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) clearly defines `"*://mail.google.com/*"` as a working pattern (which doesn't work as well).

Maybe this only applies to requests through the Content Settings API but [this site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#type-ImagesContentSetting) says that "the syntax for content setting patterns is the same as for match patterns" (with a few differences that dont apply here).

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the API, nothing surprising really as there are hundreds of those still not fixed.